# Anchor build errors due to 'getrandom' and 'let...else'

Tags: anchor, error

Anchor Version - 0.27.0
Solana Version - 1.14.19
Rust/Cargo Version 1.70

returned to my solana dev server for first time in a while. Start a project with anchor init, and attempt to build the hello world just to check everything is OK.

First I get an error I haven't seen before:

`error: target is not supported, for more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets --> src/lib.rs:286:9`

I can resolve that by adding `getrandom = { version = "0.2.2", features = ["custom"] }` to the cargo.toml file, but that seems like a hack. I've never had to use that before.

After that I get another error:

`error[E0658]: 'let...else' statements are unstable`

in relation to `solana-frozen-abi-macro-1.16.0/src/lib.rs`

I'm unable to fix that issue.

So build fails with:
`could not compile 'solana-frozen-abi-macro' due to 2 previous errors`

Is this due to the rust update to 1.70? It's the only thing I can think I've changed.

Comment: i have the same error. i don't know why. it happen previous day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the following dependencies.

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.27.0"
anchor-spl = "0.27.0"
getrandom = { version = "0.2.9", features = ["custom"] }
solana-program = "=1.14.17"
winnow="=0.4.1"
toml_datetime="=0.6.1"
```

From the Anchor discord it seems there's some compatibility issues with the 1.16 release.

> seems like new projects will not work unless they fixate the
> solana-program version to 1.14.x you can keep using that version and
> add solana-program = "=1.14.17" in your Cargo.toml

Related to this: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31428